# How to use token obtained using GoogleAuthUtil class to get user information?

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am building an Android app in which I want to authenticate user using their google account. I am using GoogleAuthUtil class to obtain token from google as shown below

```
protected String fetchToken() throws IOException{
    try {
        return GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(act, email, scope);
    } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here, act is current activity, email is the value obtained using accountpicker and scope = audience:server:client_id:X where X is the clien ID of web application.

I am getting some long result like eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImFhMTkwMjZlYTgwNjYxNjI4ZjdiYzM5OTgyNDczZTFlYTE0NTVhNWQifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJhY2Nvd....... as id token but I don't know how to use this ID token to retrieve user infromation from it.

Please help me in knowing how to get user information from ID token.

Comment: Can anyone please help, I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research, I got following.

ID token is used to verify the authenticity of the user and access token is used to know the information of e-mail id through which user is about to login. Access token is obtained in the same way as id token as shown below.

```
 oAuthscopes = "oauth2:"+"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"+" "+"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login";

protected String fetchAccessToken() throws IOException{
    try {
        return GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(act, email, oAuthscopes);
    }
    catch(GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException e){
        act.handleException(e);
    }
    catch(UserRecoverableAuthException e){
        act.handleException(e);
    }
    catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Notice the calue of oAtuthScopes. You can specify any number of scopes with space as required by your application to request permission from user.

Now, to get information of user from these scopes, do following.

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token="+accessToken);
        StringBuffer val = returnJson(url);
url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?alt=json&id_token="+idToken);
        StringBuffer valVerify = returnJson(url);
```

Method returnjSon(URL) is

```
StringBuffer returnJson(URL url) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    InputStream iStream = conn.getInputStream();

    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

    String line;
    StringBuffer val = new StringBuffer();

    while((line = read.readLine())!=null){
        val.append(line);
    }

    return val;
}
```

access token will return something like,

{ "id": "10271045940xxxxxx", "email": "xxxx", 
"verified_email": true, "name": "XXXX", "given_name": "XXXX", 
"family_name": "XXXX", "link": "https://plus.google.com/+XXXX", 
"picture": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/xxxx", "gender": "male", "locale": "XX"}

id token will return similar things. You can print that in logcat to preview.

And then,

```
        JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(val.toString());

        String email = (String)reader.get("email"));
        String name = (String)reader.get("name"));

        reader = new JSONObject(valVerify.toString());
        boolean verified = reader.getBoolean("email_verified"));
```